# Where do horses spawn in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been looking for a wild horse/donkey in minecraft, but have been unable to find one!

Which biome should I be looking in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They spawn in plains biomes.
here is a wiki page about them where all the information you need is: [Minecraft Wiki Horses](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse)

Comment: oh  i forgot that :D

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.7 (aka *The Update That Changed The World*) they can also be found in the Savannah biome as well as the Plains biome.